# Having trouble understanding how webpack bundles dependencies

Tags: typescript, three.js, webpack

I'm struggling to understand how webpack includes dependencies in a bundle.

I built a minimal-ish demo using webpack, typescript and threejs that works fine. [It's on github here](https://github.com/aellerton/bare-basic-typescript-webpack-three/)

The first problem is that I don't understand how threejs gets included in the `bundle.js`. I think it's great that it does! I just don't understand how it is included.

The second problem comes about when I tried to add in another package ([npm install --save three.trackball](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.trackball)). I added the `typings` for it as well with:

```
typings install --save --global dt~three-trackballcontrols
```

It compiles ok but when loaded in the browser fails with this error:

```
THREE.TrackballControls is not a constructor
```

I get why it does that: the trackball JS file is not in the HTML. But I can't figure out how to get it in there, partly because I can't figure out how the `three` dependency gets in there!

The trackball WIP is in the above repo as branch [WIP-trackball](https://github.com/aellerton/bare-basic-typescript-webpack-three/tree/WIP-trackball).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using angular-cli to boilerplate an angular2/typescript project. Angular-cli now uses webpack, but the webpack config is not exposed.

I was having similar issues with Three.js TrackballControls. I finally got something working by adding the appropriate package to my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
  "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
  "@types/three": "^0.83.3",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
  "three": "^0.84.0",
  "three-trackballcontrols": "^0.0.5",
  "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
```

The @types for `three` include the TrackballControls typings, but the js is not included in the `three` module.

The issue I'm still wrestling with is why I can't use the `import` statement for three-trackballcontrols in my ts

```
import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols'
```

results in a "Cannot fine module 'three-trackballcontrols'"

I resorted to

```
//import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols'
var TrackballControls = require('three-trackballcontrols');
```

and

```
this.controls = new TrackballControls(this.camera, this.container);
```

in my typescript class.

I believe in Andrew E's excellent answer that he is mixing two different implementations of a trackball for ThreeJS.

[three.trackball](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.trackball): "Adaptation of three.js trackball control to commonjs module" is a different implementation than [three-trackballcontrols](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-trackballcontrols): "A module for using THREE.TrackballControls with nodejs". I believe three-trackballcontrols is the implementation from the ThreeJS repository and matches the typings in the `three` module. I do not think there are typings readily and explicitly available for three.trackball although the interfaces are currently the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I was trying to add the TrackBallControls typescript file to my project and it was giving me this error:

```
THREE.TrackballControls is not a constructor
```

I found out my three.d.ts had no THREE.TrackballControls declaration, so i added my TrackBallControls to the end of the file adding the "export" keyword, just like this:

```
export class TrackballControls extends EventDispatcher {
    constructor(object: Camera, domElement?: HTMLElement);

    object: Camera;
    domElement: HTMLElement;

    // API
    enabled: boolean;
    screen: { left: number; top: number; width: number; height: number };
    rotateSpeed: number;
    zoomSpeed: number;
    panSpeed: number;
    noRotate: boolean;
    noZoom: boolean;
    noPan: boolean;
    noRoll: boolean;
    staticMoving: boolean;
    dynamicDampingFactor: number;
    minDistance: number;
    maxDistance: number;
    keys: number[];

    target: THREE.Vector3;
    position0: THREE.Vector3;
    target0: THREE.Vector3;
    up0: THREE.Vector3;

    update(): void;
    reset(): void;
    checkDistances(): void;
    zoomCamera(): void;
    panCamera(): void;
    rotateCamera(): void;

    handleResize(): void;
    handleEvent(event: any): void;
}
```

And added a new javascript file to my project with THREE.TrackballControls, found [here](https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js).

Later on i was having a TypeError with my update function.

```
this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
```

I just commented it and kept the:

```
this.controls.update();
```

On my render method. Everything's fine now.

Comment: Turns out that this line

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer and workaround in lieu of a "proper" answer. Hopefully it will help others.

#### TL;DR:

In `webpack.config.js` declare `THREE` as an external module:

```
externals: {
  three: 'THREE'
},
```

This stops `THREE` from being included in `bundle.js`, which has pros and cons. Overall it's a win.

HTML ends:

```
...
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that "external" doesn't mean "must come from third party site". It just means "not included in bundle.js".

#### Longer Explanation

I'd been trying to solve too many things at once. I'd figured something like this:

"WebPack is capable of taking all the dependencies, including THREE and trackball and other THREE utility modules, combine
them with `typings` information, package, minify and bundle them into a single `bundle.js`
file - so may as well do the lot"

This is true but not an effective way to keep moving.

Instead, I took a view that WebPack can package *the app code* nicely and though it *can* package the vendor code as well,
it opens up too many strange problems for limited benefit - so keep those dependencies external.

Trying to include both `THREE` and trackball controls in the `bundle.js` was very problematic.
Including `THREE` itself was straightforward and worked first time, but I couldn't
figure out why the trackball or orbit controls were so problematic.

There were multiple problems.

One is that the `dt` typing information is named incorrectly:

```
$ ls -C1 typings/globals/
three
three-orbitcontrols
three-trackballcontrols
```

These names are nice and logical - but the NPM modules are different:

```
$ grep -i three package.json
"three": "^0.77.1",
"three-orbit-controls": "^72.0.0",
"three.trackball": "0.0.1"
```

I'm not 100% sure but the names seem to cause webpack trouble in detecting which modules to include
in the bundle based on imports.

Once the import worked, the name `THREE.OrbitControls` would not resolve.
The NPM module for `OrbitControls` exports a function to be invoked, taking the
existing `THREE` module as an argument, and then adds the `OrbitControls`.
Fair enough, but the webpack initialization code doesn't know how to invoke that
function and I couldn't find a way.

The below would give compilation errors but produced JS that *did work*:

```
import OrbitControls = require('three-orbitcontrols');
THREE.OrbitControls = OrbitControls(THREE);  // compile error but still emits JS that works
```

It seemed like a *lot* of work for a simple idea: renaming directories, hacking startup code,
ignoring compile-time errors...

It dawned on me that I don't really need `THREE` to be in the bundle, and I don't really
care if the `OrbitControls` have types or not. In fact, having a smaller bundle is
faster and better.

How to get `THREE` *out* of the bundle? Just declare it `external`. Then the
default NPM and `typings` modules work fine. In fact, I'm not even sure the `typings`
modules are needed for the orbit or trackball controls.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the above and failing, with

```
"three": "^0.84.0",
"@types/three": "^0.83.0",
"three-js": ">=79.0.0",
"three-trackballcontrols": "0.0.5",
"webpack": "^1.14.0"
```

I did the following:

```
npm install save-dev three-trackballcontrols
mkdir node_modules/@types/three-trackballcontrols
cd node_modules/@types/three-trackballcontrols
cp ../three/three-trackballcontrols.d.ts ./index.d.ts
```

Next, in `index.d.ts`, I changed `class TrackballControls extends EventDispatcher {...}`  to  `export class TrackballControls extends EventDispatcher {...}`.

After that, in `index.d.ts`, at the end of the file, I added

```
declare module "three-trackballcontrols" {
  export = THREE.TrackballControls;
}
```

Next I went over to the `three` typings, `cd ../three`, and edited `index.d.ts` to change `/// <reference path="three-trackballcontrols.d.ts" />` into a comment `/* <reference path="three-trackballcontrols.d.ts" /> */`

Finally, in the renderer code, I used `import TrackballControls = require('three-trackballcontrols');` and called `controls = new TrackballControls(camera);` instead of `controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the error

*ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_three**.TrackballControls is not a constructor*

after I updated my project to angular-cli 4.0. Here is my code hope this could help someone.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "three": "^0.82.1",
    "three-trackballcontrols": "0.0.5",
    ...
  },
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/three": "0.81.0",
    ...
  }
```

Component.ts

```
...
import * as THREE from 'three';
import TrackballControls from "three-trackballcontrols";
...
this.webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
this.camera        = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            this.view_angle,
            this.width / this.height,
            this.near,
            this.far
        );
...
this.controls = new TrackballControls(this.camera, this.webGLRenderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Angular CLI (Angular 4) and got the same error:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_three_trackballcontrols__.TrackballControls is not a constructor
```

Got the code working using same as mok, thank you!

However, I noticed that this produces the error:

```js
import { TrackballControls } from 'three-trackballcontrols';
```

Import must be done in this way (like mok wrote):

```js
import TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
```